# IE6/IE7 javascript console bookmarklet (not firebug lite)

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

What bookmarklet do you use to debug javascript / DOM on IE6?

I am looking for something that has "last typed command" feature, object inspection, and perhaps DOM inspection as a bonus.

I am looking for **not firebug lite** but other alternative that people use.

Comment: It looks like IE6 bookmarklets may have a 508 character limit - https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/faq.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the console you're looking for, but if you want light debugging capability in your JavaScript, I really like Blackbird.

http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/

It gives some simple power akin to Firebug's console.log and similar functions, with fairly convenient access. I've used it frequently just to help me watch what's going on in IE.

Again, it's not a console.  You won't be getting a console, or a way to inspect DOM, but at least you get a way to output debug type content that works in IE, and it turned out that such a thing was enough for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a book-marklet but you can use Visual Web Developer Express to debug JS in IE v<8. Here's a [blog entry](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/) describing how to get it working.

For DOM inspection, I use the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en).

Comment: I had a heck of a time getting this to work until I realized I had to make IE the default browser. First time I've had IE as the default browser in years.